# Getting closest class to fadeIn on click and sibling to fadeOut

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, closest

I am trying to make a toggle like menu for showing different pieces of information, however my attempt is not working.

What I am looking for is if the user clicks on any of the titles (A, B or C) the description will `fadeIn`. That is why I tried using the `closest()` method to get the description associated with the title. Then when the user clicks on a different title, for the current one to close and the other open.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
$(".service-list-title").on("click", function(event) {
  $(this).closest('.service-list-description').fadeIn(300).siblings().closest('.service-list-description').fadeOut(300);
});
```

```css
.service-list-title {
  display: block;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
}

.service-list-description {
  display: none;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: .9rem;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="service-list">
  <li class="service-list-title">A</li>
  <p class="service-list-description">This is the content for A</p>
</div>
<div class="service-list">
  <li class="service-list-title">B</li>
  <p class="service-list-description">This is the content for B</p>
</div>
<div class="service-list">
  <li class="service-list-title">C</li>
  <p class="service-list-description">This is the content for C</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you're using `closest()`, which looks for parent elements, instead of `next()` or `siblings()` which searches for elements at the same level.

However you can make the logic much simpler by attaching the event handler to the `.service-list` element and using `find()` to get the required element to `fadeToggle()`. You can then select all the other `.service-list-description` elements and call `fadeOut()` to hide them. Try this:

```js
$(".service-list").on("click", function(event) {
  var $target = $(this).find('.service-list-description').fadeToggle(300);
  $('.service-list-description').not($target).fadeOut(300);
});
```

```css
.service-list-title {
  display: block;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  margin: 20px 0px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all .35s ease;
}

.service-list-description {
  display: none;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: .9rem;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="service-list">
  <li class="service-list-title">A</li>
  <p class="service-list-description">This is the content for A</p>
</div>
<div class="service-list">
  <li class="service-list-title">B</li>
  <p class="service-list-description">This is the content for B</p>
</div>
<div class="service-list">
  <li class="service-list-title">C</li>
  <p class="service-list-description">This is the content for C</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function below should do what you ask for:

```
$(".service-list-title").on("click", function(event) {
  $('.service-list-description').fadeOut(300); // Close any that's open
  $(this).siblings('.service-list-description').fadeIn(300); // Open new
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beekvang/oro9ue3k/